# Phonegap deviceready event not fires on device

Tags: javascript, jquery, cordova, phonegap-build

I'm working on a mobile app, but I have some problems with the phonegap. I'm begginer, but as I read the I have to simply just insert this line to work with phonegap's features.

```
<script src='phonegap.js'></script>
```

I don't know exactly the deviceready event is whats part. I try to build the app with jquery, hammer, and NO jquery mobile.

My problem is that the deviceready event is not fires. I tried lots of ways, how to bind the event listener, but I failed.

I tried to bind like this:

```
document.addEventListener('deviceready', ondeviceready);
function ondeviceready(){
    alert('wooohooo');
}
```

like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    document.addEventListener('deviceready', ondeviceready);
});

function ondeviceready(){
    alert('wooohooo');
}
```

and like this:

```
$(document).on('deviceready',ondeviceready);
function ondeviceready(){
    alert('wooohooo');
}
```

Can somebody help me?

(I tested the app on a samsung galaxy s & samsung galaxy note 2)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, I don't know why, but it is works for me.

```
function ondeviceready(){...}
document.addEventListener("deviceready", ondeviceready);
```

Comment: Just to clarify. This works because you were defining the function AFTER using it. And here you put the function definition ABOVE the document.addEventListener(...) call.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

```
document.addEventListener("deviceready", function(){
                      alert('hello');
                      });
```

Or try placing your code in following method

```
    this.init = function(){

}
```

are you still working on phonegap.js download latest version of phonegap and use cordova.js

Comment: because the phonegap build site said that insted of download the file just use the: 
<script src="phonegap.js"></script>

Or I misunderstood the documentation?

Comment: I have also tried building app from there , this doesn't work properly.Build your code in your IDE and then run.And use corodova.js instead of phonegap.js

Comment: Im using sublime text.  :(

Comment: using sublime text editor you cannot test you application,Use eclipe(for android) or xcode (for ios) and build your app in it and run in simulator.

Comment: As a I know I don't have to use IDE. http://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_embedded&v=UOjoNEUFeVE#!

I have a device where I can test the app, but I think the phonegap.js not attached to my application, while it compiles.